# Passenger on nginx fails to start after upgrading to 5.3.0 with "Assertion failed" in SpawnEnvSetupperMain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm running a Rails application (ruby 2.4.4, rails 4.2) using Phusion Passenger and nginx. This application was previously running fine.

After running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and as a result upgrading Phusion Passenger to 5.3.0, the application fails to start when I visit the web page, and I get this in the log:

```
App 12172 output: Assertion failed! src/agent/SpawnEnvSetupper/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:756: void execNextCommand(const Passenger::SpawnEnvSetupper::Context&, const string&): !shell.empty()
[ E 2018-05-11 17:43:00.0707 1144/T108 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/<app>/current: The application process exited prematurely.
  Error ID: e8a7e2db
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-iL7WYm.html

[ E 2018-05-11 17:43:00.0742 1144/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-130] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is e8a7e2db. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I found the cause here. The key was the `!shell.empty()` at the end of the error line.

I checked `/etc/passwd` and found that there was no shell defined for the user which Passenger runs under. In my case, this user is `deploy`, so I did:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash deploy
sudo service nginx restart
```

This fixed the problem and now the app starts correctly.

Comment: Indeed. This is a bug in Passenger and has already been fixed (slated for next version): https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2078